# Java8 LocalDate parse Exception

Tags: java, java-8

I'm doing a simple parse of a string in LocalDate:

```
log.debug("----->" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE").format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    log.debug("--->" +   LocalDate.parse("lun",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE",Locale.ITALY)));
```

Unfortunally, this code give this exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'lun' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=1},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1919)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1854)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
at it.Main.main(Main.java:60)
 ... 11 more
     Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=1},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)
at java.time.LocalDate$$Lambda$15/42768293.queryFrom(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1850)
... 13 more
      Exception running application it.Main
```

The fact is quite strange. Infact with numeric date and coherent pattern all works. Before I used java.util.Date and the same pattern and all worked without problems.

Have you some hints about this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Lun is the short form of "Lunedì" that is the name of the day here in Italy. It correspond to "Monday" and the short form "mon"

Comment: Yeah i know, anyway i don't think LocalDate can be used for this (you want to save only one what? lun? it's DayOfWeek). What about a helper function which converts it? Maybe using DayOfWeek too.

Comment: I have the name of the day (in short or long form) and I want to get the number of the day of week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LocalDate is supposed to represent an actual date - you only pass a day name (Monday) which can't be translated into a proper 26-May-2014, for example.

If all you want is to parse the day of week, you can use:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE", Locale.ITALY);
DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.from(fmt.parse("lun"));
```

Comment: and which should be the correct way to do this? I need this for get ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK from the object. Some hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE").parse("lun").get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

works!

Comment: I'd go with @assylias solution, as missing Locale means that for me this code would most likely fail (as I'll be running with different OS locale). Please check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-   Although it may not be an issue for you

Comment: Well, in my code it use the default Locale. So is intended that you use the name of the day ("lun") in accordance with your Locale.